# C# Selenium Mobile Emulation in landscape

Tags: c#, selenium

I'm doing some mobile UI testing using Selenium in a .Net environment using c#.

I'm able to do testing quite successfully using the chrome mobile emulation in portrait mode, but I can not found how to put the emulation in Landscape mode.

I would like to be able to programmatically rotate during testing but through research it appears this is not possible yet.

Working in Portrait mode.

```
        ChromeOptions chromeCapabilities = new ChromeOptions();         

        chromeCapabilities.EnableMobileEmulation("Apple iPhone 6");

        ChromeDriverService service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(@"C:\chromedriver");            

        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(service, chromeCapabilities);
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("www.google.com");
```

However how do I put the iPhone emulation in to a landscape orientation?

I have tried this but it does't work and the browser opens without the size limitations

```
        ChromeMobileEmulationDeviceSettings CMEDS = new ChromeMobileEmulationDeviceSettings();
        CMEDS.Width = 66;
        CMEDS.Height = 37;
        CMEDS.PixelRatio = 1.0;
        CMEDS.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 6_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10A5376e Safari/8536.25";

        ChromeOptions chromeCapabilities = new ChromeOptions();

        chromeCapabilities.EnableMobileEmulation(CMEDS);

        ChromeDriverService service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(@"C:\chromedriver");

        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(service, chromeCapabilities);
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("www.google.com");
```

Any help or advice greatly received!!
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, *it is not possible to change the screen orientation* at the moment.

Here is a related open issue:

- [Support setting screen orientation on mobile device](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=921)

---

There are [some](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/devtools/front_end/emulation/DeviceModeModel.js&sq=package:chromium&type=cs&l=135) and [few](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/devtools/front_end/emulation/DeviceOrientation.js&sq=package:chromium&type=cs) [hints](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/devtools/front_end/emulation/EmulatedDevices.js&sq=package:chromium&type=cs&l=170) in the source code that got me thinking that it might be possible to have a "landscape" oriented emulated device by *adding a custom brand new device* (how to add a device programmatically is an open question though).

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible using

```py
emulation = {"width": 384, "height": 700, "deviceScaleFactor": 10, 
         "screenOrientation": {"type": "landscapePrimary", "angle": 0}},

driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Emulation.setDeviceMetricsOverride', emulation)
```

Documentation [ChromeDeveloper-Protocoll (cdp_cmd)](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/1-3/Emulation/#method-setDeviceMetricsOverride)

possible [screenOrientation values](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/1-3/Emulation/#type-ScreenOrientation) are `"portraitPrimary", "portraitSecondary", "landscapePrimary", "landscapeSecondary"`