# where chromedriver installed by Visual studio nuget

Tags: selenium, visual-studio-2013, selenium-chromedriver, nuget-package

I am  newbie and want help please.
I am trying on selenium to automate actions to a mobile webpage. (Don't care about landscape, but just reference to its code) I am referring to this post [C# Selenium Mobile Emulation in landscape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36338760/c-sharp-selenium-mobile-emulation-in-landscape)

```
ChromeDriverService service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(@"C:\chromedriver");
```

I'm on windows7, using visual studio. I installed chromedriver through nuget package manager. I dont know what to replace on `@"C:\chromedriver"` as I don't know where chromedriver is on my machine.

Below is what I git diff from package.config, but does not seem help.
    +  
    +  
    +  
    +

Any help is appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you tried omitting the path? I don't do mobile testing but this is the way I use ChromeDriver() for web testing.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver/

> Install Chrome Driver (Win32, macOS, and Linux64) for Selenium WebDriver into your Unit Test Project.
>        "chromedriver(.exe)" is copied to bin folder from package folder when the build process.
>        NuGet package restoring ready, and no need to commit "chromedriver(.exe)" binary into source code control repository.

So you should use

```
ChromeDriverService service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(@"chromedriver.exe");
```