# Selenium mobile emulation PORTRAIT mode

Tags: python, selenium, automation, screen-orientation

I am trying to add stories to my IG account via selenium automation. I can run it successfully on mobile emulation. When I click to add a story it says rotate your device to add yo your story. It somehow thinks itself in landscape mode I think.

If I use the mobeile emulation through google developer console I can successfully add to my story.

Developer console somehow manages to identify itselfs orientation as portrait. Question is how?

I tried desiredcapabilities but had no success. There is not much info available on this topic. Can anyone guide me please? What an I missing here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: also looking for this did you find it ?

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36338760/c-sharp-selenium-mobile-emulation-in-landscape/75043455#75043455 Answer should be provided there